# LINQtoEntities include not retrieving nav property

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am using EF 4 and have Consultant, User, and OrganisationArea entities. 
Each Consultant entity has a User navigation property and each User entity can be assigned to many OrganisationAreas. I am trying to get a list of Consultants, with their embedded User property, who are assigned to a certain OrganisationArea.

My Consultant entity also has a read only property which returns the full name of a consultant by combining the forename and surname of it Users' property like so:

```
public string FullName 
{
    get { return User.Forename + " " + User.Surname; }
}
```

The following Linq works, it retrieves the Consultants that are assigned as I need but does not include its User property. Can you see why?

```
var result = from c in _dbContext.Consultants.Include("User")
             from u in _dbContext.SystemUsers
             from oa in _dbContext.OrganisationAreas
             where oa.OrganisationAreaId == _sharedInfo.LoggedInSite.OrganisationAreaId
                 && u.Current
                 && c.UserId == u.UserId
                 && c.User.Sites.Count(s => s.OrganisationAreaId == _sharedInfo.LoggedInSite.OrganisationAreaId) > 0
             select c;
```

When I create and new up an ObservableCollection of type Consultant and try to bind to the collection the FullName property, User is null.

I have resolved by selecting an anonymous type and accessing the consultant.user to project then looping through my anonymous types, as follows, but I'd like to understand what I have missed?

```
var result = from c in _dbContext.Consultants
             from u in _dbContext.SystemUsers
             from oa in _dbContext.OrganisationAreas
             where oa.OrganisationAreaId == _sharedInfo.LoggedInSite.OrganisationAreaId
                 && u.Current
                 && c.UserId == u.UserId
                 && c.User.Sites.Count(s => s.OrganisationAreaId == _sharedInfo.LoggedInSite.OrganisationAreaId) > 0
             select
             new
             {
                 Consultant = c,
                 User = c.User
             };

var theConsultants = result.ToList();
ConsultantUsers = new ObservableCollection<Consultant>();

foreach (var rec in theConsultants)
{
    ConsultantUsers.Add(rec.Consultant);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to Entities will only eager load via `Include(...)` when the shape of the query does not change (and is therefore apparent).  You are selecting from three different `DbSet<T>`s without even specifying any joins and my bet is L2E has no clue what the shape of the query should be.  `oa` doesn't even apply to the rest of the query, so why is it in there?

This is my suggestion for your query (without a reference to `_dbContext.OrganisationAreas` as I can't tell how it relates to the rest of the query):

```
_dbContext.Consultants.Include( "User" )
    .Where( c => 
        c.User.Current &&
        c.User.Sites.Any( s => 
            s.OrganisationAreaId == _sharedInfo.LoggedInSite.OrganisationAreaId ) )
```